# suitable continues integration tool

Tags: continuous-integration

My requerment is to

- Get files from CVS.
- Build in windows env
- Deploy in various servers in UNIX box

Can you please suggest a tool which can do the above?

Answer (score 0):

I recently setup a CI environment using TeamCity + Subversion + nAnt(msbuild).

For the build part, TeamCity supports quite a few BuildRunners.

nAnt itself is pretty flexible, where you can define your own "build" target and have it run whatever compiler you need. For deployment, you can similarly run your own batch files which can copy over files to your hosts, via `scp`, `sftp`, `rsh` etc.